# bannerslider acl for banner (child module) not work

Tags: adminhtml, acl

here is the adminhtml

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <bannerslider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                                    <title>Bannerslider</title>
                                    <sort_order>71</sort_order>                                 
                                </bannerslider>                             
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
                <bannerslider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                    <title>Bannerslider</title>
                    <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                    <children>
                        <bannerslider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                            <title>Manage Sliders</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </bannerslider>
                    <banner module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                        <title>Manage Banners</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>                          
                    </banner>
                        <standard_slider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                            <title>Preview Slider Styles</title>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>                          
                        </standard_slider>
                        <banner_report module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                            <title>Report Banners</title>                   
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <banner_report_all module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                                    <title>Per Slider</title>                                      
                                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                </banner_report_all>
                                <banner_report_only module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                                    <title>All Sliders</title>                                        
                                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                </banner_report_only>
                            </children>
                        </banner_report>
                        <settings module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                            <title>Settings</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        </settings>
                    </children>
                </bannerslider>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

i assigned a role allow them to acccess "manage banner", but it shows access denied when the user access it via menu, anyone knows the problem?

When I comment out the following code in `app\code\community\Magestore\Bannerslider\controllers\Adminhtml\BannerController.php` it works:

```
/*protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('banner');
}*/
```

Comment: Can you put full adminhtml.xml,config.xml and system.xml..it will be  better to check

Answer (score -1, accepted):

app\code\community\Magestore\Bannerslider\controllers\Adminhtml\BannerController.php

```
/*protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('banner');
}*/
```

fixed by comment out the above code.

Comment: This does not answer what is wrong with the configuration. I added the information to the question.

Comment: This is already the solution for the module's bug

Comment: It's band aid. Only works if you did not apply the SUPEE-6285 security patch and until then allows access to every admin user

Answer (score 2):

change controller method

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('banner');
}
```

into

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('bannerslider');
}
```

Comment: or better: `isAllowed('bannerslider/banner')`

Answer (score 0):

i think there is mistake in the your adminhtml.xml you need to define different  tags for the both system->config options and for menu.

Try by replacing following code.

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <bannerslider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                                    <title>Bannerslider</title>
                                    <sort_order>71</sort_order>                                 
                                </bannerslider>                             
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
            </children>
            <children>
                <bannerslider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                    <title>Bannerslider</title>
                    <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                    <children>
                    <bannerslider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                        <title>Manage Sliders</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    </bannerslider>
                    <banner module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                        <title>Manage Banners</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>                          
                    </banner>
                        <standard_slider module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                            <title>Preview Slider Styles</title>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>                          
                        </standard_slider>
                        <banner_report module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                            <title>Report Banners</title>                   
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <banner_report_all module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                                    <title>Per Slider</title>                                      
                                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                </banner_report_all>
                                <banner_report_only module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                                    <title>All Sliders</title>                                        
                                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                                </banner_report_only>
                            </children>
                        </banner_report>
                        <settings module="bannerslider" translate="title">
                            <title>Settings</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        </settings>
                    </children>
                </bannerslider>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Don't Forget to cleare the cache.

Comment: That's not true. `system` and `bannerslider` belong into the same `children` element.